Power Method for SVD and nuclear norm.
As an exercise from a data analysis course from my school, I have proved the convergence of the following formula. It is as an exercise related to the Power Method for leading singular vector.
The formula can be translated as dividing B to the power of l by its nuclear norm converges to projection onto its dominant eigenspace scaled by the dimension of the eigenspace.
I know that if a vector x with a compatible size is multiplied by the formula, it will approach the span of domnant eignenvectors of B, thus when l goes to infinity, the vector will lie on the corresponding eigenspace. However, this vector on the eigenspace will not be a projection of x onto the eigenspace as it is scaled by d.
I would like to know the meaning of the formula and the reason why one decides a matrix by its nuclear norm. Does this concept have a name? Is it just to keep the range of the vector within the finite boundary?
--------------------
Given some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and its singular value decomposition $A = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \sigma_i u_i v_i^\top$
consider matrix $B = A^\top A$ with its singular (eigen-) value decomposition $B = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \sigma_i^2 v_i v_i^\top$.
Let $E$ be the eigenspace related to the leading eigenvalue of matrix $B$ with dimension $d = \dim(E)$, $d \geq 1$.
Then, $$\frac{B^\ell}{\sum_{i=1}^r\sigma_i^{2\ell}} \rightarrow\frac{P_E}{d} \text{ as } \ell\rightarrow \infty$$
